# Converting CSV to an APEX List

Tags: apex, reporting, list, data, csv

I have a csv file downloaded with 1 column listing about 3000 names.  What is the simplest way to grab all these names and store them in a List to be further manipulated in Apex?

Thanks!

Comment: this offline tool is handy https://convert.town/column-to-comma-separated-list if you just need to construct an initialized one-off list variable. Watch out for heap and other limits issues though

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-off operation, you can upload it as a static resource and read through it to build your list. The following is a code I once used:

```
StaticResource csvResource = [SELECT Id, Body FROM StaticResource WHERE name ='UploadedCSV'];
String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(csvResource.Body);
final Integer bytesCount = hex.length() >> 1;
String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount];
for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i) {
    bytes[i] = hex.mid(i << 1, 2);
}
String contents = EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), 'ISO-8859-1'); */

String[] lines = contents.split('\n'); // Should be a list of all lines (in your case, names)
```

Of course, the file can also be uploaded as a file on Salesforce. Or, you can download the file in Apex from a third-party server and read through it in a similar way.